# Can we include html tags into <template> of AIML files

Tags: python, html, artificial-intelligence, aiml

I am trying to build a basic bot with the help of AIML file. Where I can ask a question and matched pattern will be returned for that pattern. Sample pattern is this in my AIML file.

```
<category>
    <pattern>TEST</pattern>
    <template>
        Hi..This is the testing pattern. How are u doing
    </template>
</category>
```

I am using [PyAIML](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAIML) package for integrating python with AIML. So, if I ask "test", I get the response as 
"Hi..This is the testing pattern. How are u doing".

```
query --->test
Answer --> Hi..This is the testing pattern. How are u doing
```

But if I change my above pattern to

```
<category>
    <pattern>TEST</pattern>
    <template>
        <html>
        <b>Hi..This is the testing pattern. </b> How are u doing
        </html>
    </template>
</category>
```

Basically If I add html tags. Then my bot does not respond. It gives blank answer for "test". What can be the problem here? Here is my code in python

```
import aiml, sys

class Chat:
    def main(self, query):
        mybot = aiml.Kernel()
        mybot.verbose(False)
        mybot.learn('test.aiml')
        chatReply = mybot.respond(query)
        return chatReply

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print Chat().main(sys.argv[1])
```

Also if html tags are not working because I am running the code in python interpreter, then how to test if it will work or not.

Answer (score 2):

AIML files are extended from XML. The HTML you have added is actually being seen as part of the XML document.

To put HTML into a tag within an XML document, you could use XML [`CDATA`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) section so that your HTML text is interpreted as purely textual data rather than XML tags.

```
<category>
    <pattern>TEST</pattern>
    <template><![CDATA[
        <html>
        <b>Hi..This is the testing pattern. </b> How are u doing
        </html>]]>
    </template>
</category>
```

This will then contain the HTML tags in the output.

Answer (score 1):

I used a alternative for this. According to this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIML) page, AIML can contain html tags. But with pyaiml, it didn't worked out. So I changed my AIML patterns as

```
<category>
    <pattern>TEST</pattern>
    <template>
        ((html))
        ((b))Hi..This is the testing pattern. ((/b)) How are u doing
        ((/html))
    </template>
</category>
```

So in the response I will be replacing '((' with '<'. I know its not a proper solution, but its a alternative.